# Flagged comment instantly marked as helpful

Tags: support, flags, comment-flags

I flagged a comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33473749/3233388) and it disappeared instantly, even if I refresh the page.

I checked the status of the flag ([Flagged Posts for Adelin - Mods only](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/3233388)) and it shows it was helpful.

How comes? Did it get enough flags to get deleted, is there some other algorithm in place or is it just a bug?